# How to convert Flux of ByteBuffer to Spring BodyInserter

Tags: java, spring-webflux, reactive

I have an usecase to read a file from s3 and publish to rest service in java. 
For the implementation, I am trying awssdk s3 API to read file which returns `Flux<ByteBuffer>` and then publish to rest service using the Spring `WebClient`.

Per my exploration, the spring `WebClient` requires BodyInserter which can be prepared using the  `BodyInserters.fromDataBuffers`. I am unable to figure out how to convert properly Flux to Flux and call WebClient exchange;

```
Flux<ByteBuffer> byteBufferFlux = getS3File(key);
        Flux<DataBuffer> dataBufferFlux= byteBufferFlux.map(byteBuffer -> {
            ?????????????Convert bytebuffer to data buffer ??????
            return dataBuffer;
        });

        BodyInserter<Flux<DataBuffer>, ReactiveHttpOutputMessage> inserter = BodyInserters.fromDataBuffers(dataBufferFlux);
```

Any suggestions how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert using `DefaultDataBuffer` which you can create via the `DefaultDataBufferFactory`

```
DataBufferFactory dataBufferFactory = new DefaultDataBufferFactory();

Flux<DataBuffer> buffer = getS3File(key).map(dataBufferFactory::wrap);

BodyInserter<Flux<DataBuffer>, ReactiveHttpOutputMessage> inserter =
    BodyInserters.fromDataBuffers(buffer);
```

You don't actually need a BodyInserter at all though if using Webclient you can the following method signature for `body()`

```
<T, P extends Publisher<T>> RequestHeadersSpec<?> body(P publisher, Class<T> elementClass);
```

Which you can then pass your `Flux<ByteBuffer>` directly into, whilst specifying the Class to use

```
    WebClient.create("http://someUrl")
            .post()
            .uri("/someUri")
            .body(getS3File(key),ByteBuffer.class)
```

Comment: I'm surprised how hard it was to google an answer. Faced same problem, your solution helped a lot, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may not need dataBufferFlux and should be able to write the Flux to your rest endpoint. Try this:

```
  Flux<ByteBuffer> byteBufferFlux = getS3File(key);

  BodyInserter<Flux<ByteBuffer>, ReactiveHttpOutputMessage> = BodyInserters.fromPublisher(byteBufferFlux, ByteBuffer.class);
```